# Unable to access /root in CentOS server with ' VSFTPD'

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I'm new to linux administration and am trying to configure `vsftpd` on my CentOS server to give me ftp access to the `/root` folder. Currently, I have access to folders in the parent directory, but not that one in particular. When trying to access `/root` through my ftp client I get the following:

```
Server said: Failed to change directory.

Error -125: remote chdir failed
```

I can access `/root` as a `root` user through my terminal.

Here are the `vsftpd` config settings

```
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
ftpd_banner=Welcome to ViceCraft FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=YES
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
#listen_ipv6=YES

local_root=/

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Comment: Can you suggest a reason why files in root should be accessible by a totally insecure protocol?   I'm concerned that you might not see the problem with sending root's username/password in cleartext.   And /root should not be accessible by non-root users in any form - /root/ should have 750 permissions and be owned by root:root

Comment: What is in   /etc/vsftpd/user_list    and     /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers   and     /etc/ftpusers     ?

Comment: I have a minecraft installation there and need to be able to upload files to it's directory sub-folders

Comment: @Criggie well then I need to be able to sftp to the server as root so that I can make changes to an existing folder.

Comment: You need to rethink your system's permissions.   "just do it as root"  is not a good solution.   Your minceraft process should not be running as root, and should not require root access.  sftp or scp would be a better solution than ftp, but that doesn't address the underlying "why root?" problem

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to get the Minecraft serve to work when it's not under root. If I move the folder to somewhere else, it won't work. And all instructions online are telling me to install it in root.

Comment: @JoshuaHowell Installing it as root is different than giving the service root rights. On proper servers you often have separate users/groups per service, this is a good idea from a security standpoint. And some services normally refuse to work with too many rights.

Comment: It should not be possible. If you succeed, please write it down, so that I can file a report to VSFTPD team to secure it down. Thanks.